# Adding a link to javascript string

Tags: javascript, html, string, momentjs, href

I have a calendar feature that uses javascript and moment.js, which works fine. Though I would like to add links, similar to href with html, to the strings containing eventName, so that the eventName displayed within the calendar are clickable links. I've included the function and strings including each eventName.. Any advice?

```js
!function() {

var today = moment();
  
function Calendar(selector, events) {
  this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
  this.events = events;
  this.current = moment().date(1);
  this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
   ev.date = moment(ev.date);
  });
  this.draw();
  var current = document.querySelector('.today');
}
  
Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
  //Create Header
  this.drawHeader();
  
  //Draw Month
  this.drawMonth();
  
  this.drawLegend();
}
  
Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
  var self = this;
  if(!this.header) {
    //Create the header elements
    this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
    this.header.className = 'header';
  
    this.title = createElement('h1');
  
    var right = createElement('div', 'right');
    right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });
  
    var left = createElement('div', 'left');
    left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });
  
    //Append the Elements
    this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
    this.header.appendChild(right);
    this.header.appendChild(left);
    this.el.appendChild(this.header);
  }
  
  this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
}
  
Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  
  if(this.month) {
    this.oldMonth = this.month;
    this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
    this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
      self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
      self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
      self.backFill();
      self.currentMonth();
      self.fowardFill();
      self.el.appendChild(self.month);
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
      }, 16);
    });
  } else {
      this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
      this.el.appendChild(this.month);
      this.backFill();
      this.currentMonth();
      this.fowardFill();
      this.month.className = 'month new';
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
  var clone = this.current.clone();
  var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
  
  if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }
  
  clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);
  
  for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
    this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
  var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
  var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
  
  if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }
  
  for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
    this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
  var clone = this.current.clone();
  
  while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
    this.drawDay(clone);
    clone.add('days', 1);
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
  if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
    this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
    this.month.appendChild(this.week);
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
  var self = this;
  this.getWeek(day);
  
  //Outer Day
  var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
  outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.openDay(this);
  });
  
  //Day Name
  var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));
  
  //Day Number
  var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));
  
  
  //Events
  var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
  this.drawEvents(day, events);
  
  outer.appendChild(name);
  outer.appendChild(number);
  outer.appendChild(events);
  this.week.appendChild(outer);
}
  
Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
  if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
    var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
      if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
        memo.push(ev);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);
  
    todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
      var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
      element.appendChild(evSpan);
    });
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
  classes = ['day'];
  if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
    classes.push('other');
  } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
    classes.push('today');
  }
  return classes.join(' ');
}
  
Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
  var details, arrow;
  var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
  var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);
  
  var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');
  
  //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
  if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
    details = currentOpened;
    arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
  } else {
    //Close the open events on differnt week row
    //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
    if(currentOpened) {
      currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      });
      currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
        currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      });
      currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      });
      currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      });
      currentOpened.className = 'details out';
    }
  
    //Create the Details Container
    details = createElement('div', 'details in');
  
    //Create the arrow
    var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');
  
    //Create the event wrapper
  
    details.appendChild(arrow);
    el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
  }
  
  var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
    if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
      memo.push(ev);
    }
    return memo;
  }, []);
  
  this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);
  
  arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
}
  
Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
  //Remove any events in the current details element
  var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
  var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));
  
  events.forEach(function(ev) {
    var div = createElement('div', 'event');
    var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
    var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);
  
    div.appendChild(square);
    div.appendChild(span);
    wrapper.appendChild(div);
  });
  
  if(!events.length) {
    var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
    var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Events');
  
    div.appendChild(span);
    wrapper.appendChild(div);
  }
  
  if(currentWrapper) {
    currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
    currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
      currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    });
    currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
      currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    });
    currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
      currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    });
    currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
      currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    });
  } else {
    ele.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
}
  
Calendar.prototype.drawLegend = function() {
  var legend = createElement('div', 'legend');
  var calendars = this.events.map(function(e) {
    return e.calendar + '|' + e.color;
  }).reduce(function(memo, e) {
    if(memo.indexOf(e) === -1) {
      memo.push(e);
    }
    return memo;
  }, []).forEach(function(e) {
    var parts = e.split('|');
    var entry = createElement('span', 'entry ' +  parts[1], parts[0]);
    legend.appendChild(entry);
  });
  this.el.appendChild(legend);
}
  
Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
  this.current.add('months', 1);
  this.next = true;
  this.draw();
}
  
Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
  this.current.subtract('months', 1);
  this.next = false;
  this.draw();
}
  
window.Calendar = Calendar;
  
function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
  var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
  if(className) {
    ele.className = className;
  }
  if(innerText) {
    ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
  }
  return ele;
}
  }();

  !function() {
    var data = [
      { eventName: 'Dinner under the stars', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-10' },
      { eventName: 'Wine tasting', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-08' },
      { eventName: 'BBQ Festival', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-10' },
      { eventName: 'Food Event', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-10' },
      { eventName: 'Wine Event', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-12' },
      { eventName: 'Wine Event', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-18' },
      { eventName: 'Food Event', calendar: 'Food/Beverage', color: 'orange', date: '2019-03-20' },

  
      { eventName: 'Team vs Team', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue', date: '2019-03-01' },
      { eventName: 'Team vs Team', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue', date: '2019-03-02' },
      { eventName: 'Kickball Event', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue', date: '2019-04-04' },
      { eventName: 'Team vs Team', calendar: 'Sports', color: 'blue', date: '2019-04-01' },
  
      { eventName: 'Haunted tour', calendar: 'History', color: 'yellow', date: '2019-03-04' },
      { eventName: 'Art museum', calendar: 'History', color: 'yellow', date: '2019-03-19' },
      { eventName: 'Civil War tour', calendar: 'History', color: 'yellow', date: '2019-03-20' },
      { eventName: 'History Event', calendar: 'History', color: 'yellow', date: '2019-03-31' },
  
      { eventName: 'Outdoor movie', calendar: 'Outdoors', color: 'green', date: '2019-03-02' },
      { eventName: 'Nature walk', calendar: 'Outdoors', color: 'green', date: '2019-03-10' },
      { eventName: 'White water rafting', calendar: 'Outdoors', color: 'green', date: '2019-03-14' },
      { eventName: 'Nature Event', calendar: 'Outdoors', color: 'green', date: '2019-03-17' }
    ];
  
    var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);
  
  }();
```

```html
<body>

<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where's the Calendar function coming from? The Calendar function is where the solution should be looked for.

Comment: Hey there, I've added the rest of the code for the calendar feature. : ) Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving a redirect on the calendar click is something that you have to choose how to do, there is no best way, especially since we don't know  how your calendar constructor works. I will just answer your question:

> Adding a link to javascript string?

If you don't know where the links will lead beforehand then you have no choice but to add a field yourself.

In case you do have some way of determining the href do this after you declare your array:

```
const linkMaker = (string) => {
  const href="/path/to/determine/somehow";
  return `<a href={href}>{string}</a>`;
}

dataWithLinks = data.map(dataObject => ({...dataObject, eventName: linkMaker(dataObject.eventName)}));
```